# Best approach for a batch email process that accesses a web app's database

Tags: c#, email, batch-processing

I have a C# web app that needs a batched nightly email process generated out of it - I'm trying to figure out the best approach for this.

In an application I managed in the past we had a separate email program that did the generation and was scheduled to run with the server's Task Scheduler. The problem with this is that a lot of the DAL is duplicated between the web app and the scheduled program.

I was wondering if anybody had a better approached to this scenario, or if anyone had any suggestions going forward. I keep thinking there has to be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of the DAL is duplicated"?  Can't both applications just use the same DAL project(s)?

Comment: Have you considered creating a web service or a windows service that consumes the web service, also make sure that you separate the DAL from business logic to eliminate redundancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only reason you don't want to use a separate project to send your email is the common Dal code, then break your Dal code into a separate project and have both applications share the some code base.

Trying to set up your web application to do scheduled processing is going to be painful and flaky.  If you really don't want to have a shared Dal lib then setup a web service in your web application that can be called by a scheduled task that batches and send the email.

But I can say from personal experience, in the long run you are going to be much happier splitting your dal off and using a shared code base for both apps

Comment: Thanks. We already have the dal and bll in a separate project. I'll just drop it into my email program. I was just wondering if there was another technique to accomplish this that I didn't know about. Appreciate the timely answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, it's perfectly capable of sending emails on its own. See

- [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [Database Mail and SQL Mail Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177580.aspx)
- [Database Mail Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189879%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Queue up our pending mails into a table. Format the body the way you'd like and store it as a columns in the pending emails table. Once you've got the schema set up for your pending email queue, it's pretty trivial to write a stored procedure that gets executed as a periodic task to iterate over the pending email queue, send each email and remove it from the queue. You can use either SQL Server's own task scheduler or the Windows Scheduled Task daemon. Don't forget to include logging in your solution if the emails are at all important.

Sometimes useful to move the message to an archive table so as to allow for resending it if necessary (Don't forget to configure a purge policy and agent for this).

I had a system set up like this. Rather than squirt the emails off nightly, the task ran every few minutes or so.

Comment: I've done this before, except I've used a program that would run the send every 15 minutes. I don't recall ATM why we didn't explore this option. Good to keep in mind. Thanks.